# Any existing ring buffers in .NET that can have multiple consumers?

Tags: .net, thread-safety, circular-buffer

Wondering if there is an existing ring buffer in .NET that has only one writer, but can have multiple consumers?

Needless to say, there are multiple threads reading from this buffer (but only one thread writing), so the implementation would have to be thread safe.

Comment: See [Concurrent Collections in the .NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/gg274329).

Comment: See [MSDN Blogs >> C# Frequently Asked Questions >> Blocking Collection and the Producer-Consumer Problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/08/12/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this article its really quite good http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx I would suggest you want the `BlockingCollection<T>`

Comment: Thanks! Ended up using the BlockingCollection, as the consuming thread has to wait for the producer thread to create new data. Attempting to use ConcurrentQueue and a polling system with Yield() saw CPU rise from 2% to 10% on average.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) and [similar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287108.aspx) - these are thread-safe and very fast since most things are implemented lock-free... they can handle multiple consumers and even multiple writers...

For a nice tutorial etc. see http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/02/10/c.net-little-wonders-the-concurrent-collections-1-of-3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Whenever buffering + threading in .NET you want Rx. See `new ReplayBuffer<T>(int)`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229429.aspx

Last I heard Disruptor.NET has a lot of intricate details you need to understand before you get any performance benefits.  I would suggest modelling in Rx first and moving to Disruptor when you have small (<10k) data sets working in Rx, then focus on performance.